# Override CSS rules

Tags: javascript, css, overriding

I want to find Nodes in my DOM tree which have a class name: `ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all`. When I find them I want to override their CSS with my CSS. But I cannot make my code work:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all");
        for( var i=0; i<p.length; p++) {
                p[i].style.width = 5 + "px !important";
                p[i].style.height = 5 + "px !important";
            }




<div class="ui-slider ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all dhSliderDesktop ui-slider-vertical" style="visibility: visible;"><div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="height: 100%;"></div><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="bottom: 100%;"></a></div>
```

[image]
[image]

My element creation:

```
var slider = document.createElement("div");
        $(slider).slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
        });

        if(isMobile)
          $(slider).slider().addClass("dhSliderMobile");
      else
          $(slider).slider().addClass("dhSliderDesktop");
```

Comment: Can we pls have some HTML and more scripts? BTW why are you doing 5 + "px !important" when you can just do "5px !important"

Comment: Are you using jQuery? From the classes used, I think you are using jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery

```
var slider = document.createElement("div");
$(slider).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
});

var items = $('.ui-slider-handle', slider);
console.log('Test: ', items.length, items)
console.log('HTML: ', slider.html())
$('.ui-slider-handle', slider).each(function(i, v){
    var style = $(this).attr('style');
    style += (style? ';' : '') + 'height: 5px !important; width: 5px !important;'
    $(this).attr('style', style)
})
```

Another solution to try

```
var slider = document.createElement("div");
$(slider).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
});

$('.ui-slider-handle', slider).addClass('myoverride');
```

then add the css rule

```
.myoverride {
    height: 5px !important;
    width: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Jacob Check this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PayHV/2/) the overrides are working. Your styles may have some other problems also. Can you inspect the styles of the element using developer toolbar/firebug

Comment: I think the problem is the code is not running on dom ready, I'll update my post

Comment: can you check the console, I'd added a log statement, get the message for debugging purpose

Comment: Check the image in the previous post

Comment: it says fond `0`, that is the problem

Comment: is the content dynamically loaded or it is present when the page is loaded? I'd changed it to a run on dom ready did you do that (wrapped the code inside `$(function(){});`

Comment: can you run `$('.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all').length` in your console

Comment: it looks like the selector used `$('.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all')` is wrong

Comment: Can you add a unique class to the element to which you want to apply this behaviour like `mytestclass` and change `$('.ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all')` to `$('.mytestclass')`

Comment: This is actually what I wanted to achieve in the first place because the content is created dynamically.

Comment: how is this dynamic content added to the page, is it loaded via ajax

Comment: I create it in Javascript!

Comment: Also try removing `!important`, it may not be required, if it is not required let me know, the code can be much cleaner

Comment: Then I would recommend you to create a css rule with `!important` and assign the class instead of changing the style

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `getElementsByClassName` method is not cross browser compatible.

You can use jquery `$(".ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all")` selector or write your own cross browser code to capture nodes by class name like this one:

http://javascript.ru/unsorted/top-10-functions#8-getelementsbyclass

Answer (score 0):

1. Your classname selector won't work because it doesn't have FULL classname. This would be correct `ui-slider ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all dhSliderDesktop ui-slider-vertical`. But if that's generated by your script, then I think you're gonna have to turn to jQuery for a better selector. Plus getElementsByClassName is not cross-browser.

   jQuery version of the selector:

   ```
   $(".ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all")
   ```

   or you can simply assign an ID for your element and call it with `getElementByID` instead of classname.
2. Your loop is a bit off. It should be i++ and not p++.
3. style property in javascript can't recieve "!important".

By fixing your script, this should work.

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-slider ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all dhSliderDesktop ui-slider-vertical");

for( var i=0; i<p.length; i++) {
     p[i].style.width = "5px";
     p[i].style.height = "5px";
     console.log(p[i].style);
}
```

Comment: I have multiple element so I can't assign an ID.

Answer (score 0):

USING Document.querySelector 
Browser compatibility: IE8+

```
alert(document.querySelectorAll(".ui-slider-handle.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all").length)
```